# Does a ping response contain MAC address?

Tags: networking, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I am trying to use an esp8266 to find what ip addresses are registered on the same subnet and their mac addresses for a home automation  project. Does a ping response contain the MAC address of the device or is it possible to ask for it over a local network.

Comment: You want to use a RARP message.  Edit: Err, just an ARP message.  RARP is the other way 'round.

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/64281/how-to-get-mac-address-via-ip

might be handy, scroll down to second answer. You'll have to utilize Address Resolution Protocol or ARP.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson, RARP actually returns your own IP address from another host, like a gateway. It is not actually the reverse of ARP, but the opposite of ARP.

Answer (score 4):

On a *nix system, you can run `arping <some-ip>` to get the MAC address of a machine on the same network (only those machines which can get your packet without being routed through a network, of course).

As rodolk suggested, you can run `pcap` and look at the ethernet frames as well. Ethernet frames contain the source MAC, and destination MAC and ethernet type.
Something like this:

```
uint8_t  ether_dhost[ETHER_ADDR_LEN];    /* destination MAC address */
uint8_t  ether_shost[ETHER_ADDR_LEN];    /* source MAC address */
uint16_t ether_type;                     /* packet type ID */
```

You could sniff packets and parse the ethernet headers, or you could run an `arping`, I think that should serve your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Ping does not reveal the MAC address. It simply tells you if a server is online or not.
You can use "nbtstat -a ip" command on windows to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to obtain the MAC address (layer 2) given an IP address (layer 3) you can use RARP. Otherwise, if you use ping, at layer 3 you won't have access to the MAC address of the ping response. However you can use [pcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.html) to sniff the network, read the ping reply with the apporpriate pcap filter, and obtain the MAC address from the arriving Ethernet frame. You can also use packet sockets to get layer 2 frames. pcap should be useful.